# Service worker offline - administration not working

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I install service worker to my website. I have Front and Admin module. On the Front a add service worker like this

```
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceworker.js', {
            scope: './'
        });
    }
```

And service worker like this

```
 'use strict';

 var cacheVersion = 1;
 var currentCache = {
   offline: 'offline-cache' + cacheVersion
 };
 const offlineUrl = '/offline';

 this.addEventListener('install', event => {
   event.waitUntil(
     caches.open(currentCache.offline).then(function(cache) {
       return cache.addAll([
         '/assets/base/images/404-parallax.png',
         offlineUrl
       ]);
     })
   );
 });

 this.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
   // request.mode = navigate isn't supported in all browsers
   // so include a check for Accept: text/html header.
   if (event.request.mode === 'navigate' || (event.request.method === 'GET' && event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html'))) {
     event.respondWith(
       fetch(event.request.url).catch(error => {
         // Return the offline page
         return caches.match(offlineUrl);
       })
     );
   } else {
     // Respond with everything else if we can
     event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request)
       .then(function(response) {
         return response || fetch(event.request);
       })
     );
   }
 });
```

offline page is example.com/offline

frontend looks OK, but if I want go to administration example.com/administration I've got ERR_FAILED and in console is `"https://www.example.com/administration/" resulted in a network error response: a redirected response was used for a request whose redirect mode is not "follow".`

But if I open DevTools and press ctrl+shift+R then the page works. But if I haven't open DevTools its not working.

I'am realy confused. Maybe is some problem with scope of serviceworker, but I try many optins and still not workin.

Comment: Do you in which case the fetch for your admin page falls?

Comment: If I open DevTools and press ctrl+shift+R I think that is work because serviceworker is removed with reload cache. But then if I press only ctrl+R  again not working. I have different layouts for frontend and backend and registered service worker only on frontend. I try registered worker on backend but still not working

Comment: I meant if you know if the problem is in the first or second part of your `if`

Comment: No, I dont know. If I go to example.com/somePage -> working another pages working too, but /administration not working

Comment: I had this same problem, and this recent article worked for me:
https://paul.kinlan.me/offline-fallback-page-with-service-worker/